# Anything wrong with this chicken/can undercooked chicken be white inside?

Tags: chicken, raw, cook

I was trying to fry some chicken without getting the outside to crust and so fried on lower than usual heat. Please see pics of the meat.

1. I am concerned the chicken may not have cooked properly however as you can see from the pics it is white and when eating they were all white inside.  I know a thermometer is the best way to know however it's too late now and I'm just wondering if it's white does that mean its done or could it still be under cooked?
2. In other questions, I was trying to cook meat well done without letting a crust develop on the outside.  People here told me this couldn't be done and cooking any meats well done would lead to a crust being formed on the surface of the meat.  In this chicken I coooked, it did all come out white and the surface was soft and easy to eat, it was not crusty or hard.  however in the last pic you can see the texture of the surface is different from the inside.  Would you regrd this as a crusty surface as was referred to others in previous questions or not?
3. Bearing in mind the surface is not crusty and it was cooked on a low heat, are you able to tell any mistakes/anything else from the pictures? It may be the rice I mixed it with, however unless I am mistake the chicken did feel a bit watery.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your chicken looks fine. It seems as if you have succeeded in getting the meat done without it drying out, which is always great!

The surface does not look 'crusty' and as you say it's soft and easy to eat, I would say it's a success.

Answer (score 1):

The first & last pictures look OK. The one in the middle, I'd want to prod a bit more with a fork; it's almost impossible to tell from just a photo.

However, overall it looks more like it was boiled rather than fried. It just looks sad & unloved.

If you want 'crustless' [until this past week I've never known anyone refer to the outside of fried meat as a 'crust'] then why don't you just slice it really thinly & flash it.
That way you can cook it within two minutes if your heat is high enough. If it's standard supermarket "10% added water" stuff, then by the time the water is coming off, it's cooked. You know it's cooked because it's thin enough that you can watch it go from translucent to white, on both sides as you throw it round the pan; as soon as no piece shows any pink on the outside, it's done on the inside because it's only 2mm thick.

Another thought - that looks like a pretty hefty chicken breast.
A breast of maybe 150g should be quick to cook & tender. One of 300g is going to start to get that 'big fibre' look & be much chewier. It also won't have the same smell or taste, they get gamier as they get bigger.